# Знаки вопроса вместо перевода при использовании yandex translate api

Tags: java, яндекс-переводчик

Пишу на java. При переводе с различных языков на русский, переводчик яндекс api работает нормально. Но при переводе с русского или украинского(другие языки, частично использующие кириллицу, я не пробовал) на английский вместо перевода я получаю символы вопроса. Тоже самое с украинского на русский. Из чего я сделал вывод, что проблема в кириллице. Может при отправке кириллица как-то искажается.
Вот мой код

```
public String translate(String textToTranslate) throws Exception{
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    HttpClient client = builder.build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate");
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+translatorsEntity.getIamToken());
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    json.append("{");
    json.append("\"folderId\":\""+translatorsEntity.getCatalogId()+"\",");
    json.append("\"texts\":[\""+textToTranslate+"\"],");
    json.append("\"targetLanguageCode\":\"ru\"");
    json.append("}");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(httpEntity.getContent(), writer, "UTF-8");
    String postRespose = writer.toString();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return getTranslateResult(gson.fromJson(postRespose, Object.class));
}
```

Пробовал жестко задавать, с какого языка я перевожу, добавляя

```
json.append("\"sourceLanguageCode\":\"ru\"");
```

но проблема осталась. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, просьба помочь.

Upd1. Я попробовал отправить текст через curl. Файл body.json приложил отдельно. Он был в кодировке utf-8. Русский текст перевёлся корректно.Я проверил кодировки строк IDEA. Оказалось, что кодировка английского текста, который переводится корректно везде - ISO-8859-1, а русского текста UTF-8. Но в файле, который я отправлял через curl, весь json был UTF-8. Как же тогда там он перевелся нормально, а при отправке через java(IDEA) UTF-8 не воспринимается яндекс транслейтом

Upd2. Я попробовал тот файл отправить не через curl, а через java. И русский текст нормально перевёлся. Получается, что дело именно в `StringEntity`, которая передается в теле `httpPost`.

Comment: Есть впечатление, что символы вопроса - это "следы" попыток преобразовать кодировку. То есть, в "нормальном и привычном большинству людей" мире есть одна кодирорвка, и она называется UTF-8. Но так как она одна - никто и не задумывается о том, что есть какие то "кодировки". А вот когда опускаешься в зловонные глубины байтов, то оказывается, что там есть представление руссских букв в виде их кодов, и это не всегда ascii коды... ну и понеслось... Может быть, попробовать получить промежуточное состояние- например, поймать обмен данными при помощи какого нить wireshark или fiddler?

Comment: @S.H., я обновил вопрос, посмотри пожалуйста

Comment: > Как же тогда там он перевелся нормально, а при отправке через java(IDEA) UTF-8 не воспринимается яндекс транслейтом - это очень хороший вопрос! Я рассуждаю так: у yandex есть два источника данных: тело http-запроса и его заголовки. Тело Вы полностью контролируете. Но,  мне кажется, что 1) curl не использует умолчания, он вообще не делает того, о чём его не просят 2) а вот у модуля, которым всё шлётся из java - может быть своё мнение на тему http - заголовков. Может, их перехватить? я бы посмотрел в сторону https://www.telerik.com/fiddler для перехвата и postman для экспериментов

Comment: @S.H., я попробовал тот файл отправить не через curl, а через java. И русский текст нормально перевёлся. Получается, что дело именно в StringEntity, которая передается в теле httpPost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось до боли простым. Заменить строку

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
```

на

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(),ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```